# Swift create subclass for transparent navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have done transparent navigation bar in multiple viewcontroller with help of below code. I would like to reduce the lines of code in main class files also try to avoid code duplication. So, I need to create subclass for below code. Please help me

```
    // NavigationBar Tranparant
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = .clear
```

Comment: You should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833384/how-to-customize-uinavigationbar-for-the-entire-app).
Btw you don't need to use `self` here.

Comment: I am expecting subclass @kkiermasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an extension:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func setTransparentNavBar() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
    }
}
```

If you want transparent navigation bar in a UIViewController just call setTransparentNavBar in the viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating your elements by storyboards so simply create a subclass of `UINavigationBar` and add your properties inside `awakeFromNib` function.

Now in your storyboards, select the navigationBar of the navigationController and give it the class(from identity inspector) you have just created.

**Example for your UINavigationBar subclass:**

```
import UIKit
class AppBaseNavigationBar : UINavigationBar{
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()

        self.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black
        ]
        self.isTranslucent = true 
    }
}
```

However if you want to use it by code i.e ( `let nav = UINavigationController(navigationBarClass: AppBaseNavigationBar.self, toolbarClass : nil)` )

you need to add `override init(frame: CGRect)` and `required init?(coder: NSCoder` (the latter is required) since we are not coming from Nib and the `awakeFromNib` will not be called.

So your subclass will be as follow :

```
import UIKit
class AppBaseNavigationBar : UINavigationBar{


    override init(frame: CGRect) {//for using custom view in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupNavBar()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {// for using CustomView in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupNavBar()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setupNavBar()

    }

    func setupNavBar(){
        // To avoid duplicate code, move your properties to a function.
        self.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        self.shadowImage = UIImage()

        self.titleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black
        ]
        self.isTranslucent = true
    }
}
```

`override init(frame: CGRect)` is used when you create the view programmatically. (That's why we have implemented since we are going to create our NavigationController programmatically)

`required init?(coder: NSCoder)` is used when the view is created from storyboard/xib.

Since the latter is required we have also setup our nav here..